# Table view cells not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I seem to have done everything I'm supposed to, but my table view cells aren't showing when I use two different subclasses of UITableViewCell each with an xib file, except for the integer values I assigned to textLabel!.text at the end of tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) right before the return statement.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let items = [0, 1]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(DueDateSwitchTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell")

        let xibDueDateSwitchTableViewCell = UINib(nibName: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)

        tableView.register(xibDueDateSwitchTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell")

        tableView.register(DueDatePickerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell")

        let xibDueDatePickerTableViewCell = UINib(nibName: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)

        tableView.register(xibDueDatePickerTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        print("tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)", "indexPath.row=", indexPath.row)

        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        switch indexPath.section {

        case 0:

            print("\tcase 0")

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDateSwitchTableViewCell

            cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        case 1:

            print("\tcase 1")

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDatePickerTableViewCell

            cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)

            cell.datePicker.date = Date()

        default:

            break

        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)

        return cell

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells you create inside each `case` statement is ignored and left unused. Your `return cell` line is returning the first `cell` variable which is your empty cell.

Since you only have two possible cells, I suggest redoing your code as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDateSwitchTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDatePickerTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
        cell.datePicker.date = Date()

        return cell
    }
}
```

You also need to fix your `viewDidLoad`. There should only be one call to `register` per reuse identifier. You have two each.

Comment: Ok.  Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept the answer that best solves the issue in your question. Click on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `ViewDidLoad` Method

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell")

let nib = UINib(nibName: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell")
```

And Change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dataSource method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
      print("tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)", "indexPath.row=", indexPath.row)        
      if indexPath.section == 0 {    
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDateSwitchTableViewCell    
            cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)   
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            cell.textLabel!.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
            return cell
        }
        else {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDatePickerTableViewCell
             cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
             cell.datePicker.date = Date()
             cell.textLabel!.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
             return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xibs the no need to register UITableViewCell subclass in register method just register using nib

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let xibDueDateSwitchTableViewCell = UINib(nibName: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)

        tableView.register(xibDueDateSwitchTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell")

        let xibDueDatePickerTableViewCell = UINib(nibName: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)

        tableView.register(xibDueDatePickerTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell")

    }
```

in cellForRowAt method you're returning a empty cell by assigning cell to UITableViewCell(), change it return a CustomCells which you have registered in ViewDidLoad based on indexPath.section as numberOfSection method returning 2 sections

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
            case 0:
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDateSwitchTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDateSwitchTableViewCell
                cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                return cell
            case 1:
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DueDatePickerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DueDatePickerTableViewCell
                cell.label.text = String(items[indexPath.section].hashValue)
                cell.datePicker.date = Date()
            return cell
            default:
                fatalError("Unexpected section \(indexPath.section)")
        }
    }
```